# Classic thesis - customising the header to include chapter titles

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I am using the classic thesis template and in my document, I have modified the header to include the chapter heading in the top right of each page, from the advice given here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJVK.png). However, on the last page of the chapter, the name in the header changes to that of the next chapter. How do I ensure the modified header is applied to all pages within the same chapter?

I've included a MWE and a screenshot of the problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude=true,footinclude]{report}% or book for the standard book class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{../Visuals/}{../Visuals/Chapter_1/}{../Visuals/Chapter_2/}{../Visuals/Chapter_3/}{../Visuals/Chapter_4/}{../Visuals/Chapter_5/}{../Visuals/Chapter_6/}}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Libraryv1.69,test}%multiple .bib files here for different chapters
%\addbibresource{test}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage{titleps}%fancy page borders? 
\usepackage[left=4.0cm, right=4cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\pagestyle{scrheadings} % <--- Affects the page header 
% and page number in the footer.
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\leftmark}  % comment out to 

\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
% Remove section number from heading

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\doublespacing 
\begin{document}

%CHAPTER_1
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\chapter{Project 1}

%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use more than one package for page header and footer! Package `classicthesis` loads package `scrlayer-scrpage`.  Therefore you have to remove package `titleps`.

Example (I have removed all the unrelated stuff):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude=true,footinclude]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}% loads package scrlayer-scrpage and sets page style scrheadings

\usepackage{mathptmx}% replaces obsolete package times
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

%\usepackage{titleps}% <- remove this package!!

\usepackage[left=4.0cm, right=4cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\pagestyle{scrheadings}% <- not needed
\clearpairofpagestyles% <- replaces outdated \cleardscrheadfoot
\ohead{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% <- short version of \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\chapter{Project 1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mix of classes, packages and options.

**Option 1**

Use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}`  and `titleps` to setup the headers.

**Option 2**

Use

`\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true]{scrreprt}`,  the KOMA-Script report, and its own way to specify the page headers and footers
(and remove `titleps` !)

**Option 1**

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}% or book for the standard book class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{../Visuals/}{../Visuals/Chapter_1/}{../Visuals/Chapter_2/}{../Visuals/Chapter_3/}{../Visuals/Chapter_4/}{../Visuals/Chapter_5/}{../Visuals/Chapter_6/}}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%%%\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{Libraryv1.69,test}%multiple .bib files here for different chapters
%\addbibresource{test}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 

%% ********************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} 
\usepackage{titleps}%fancy page borders? 
\newpagestyle{main}[\sffamily]{
    \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]% even pages if twoside
    {}{}{\chaptertitle} % odd pages
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}% 
} 
\pagestyle{main}

\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small\sffamily]{
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
%% *******************************************

\usepackage[left=4.0cm, right=4cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

%   %\pagestyle{scrheadings} % <--- Affects the page header 
%   %% and page number in the footer.
%   %\clearscrheadfoot
%   %\ohead{\leftmark}  % comment out to 
%   %
%   %\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
%   %
%   %\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
%   %% Remove section number from heading   

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\doublespacing 
\begin{document}
    
    %CHAPTER_1
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum
    
    \chapter{Project 1}
    
    %\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Option 2**

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true]{scrreprt}% KOMA-Script report

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{../Visuals/}{../Visuals/Chapter_1/}{../Visuals/Chapter_2/}{../Visuals/Chapter_3/}{../Visuals/Chapter_4/}{../Visuals/Chapter_5/}{../Visuals/Chapter_6/}}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % added <<<
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{Libraryv1.69,test}%multiple .bib files here for different chapters
%%\addbibresource{test}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 

%\usepackage{titleps}%fancy page borders?  REMOVE <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[left=4.0cm, right=4cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\pagestyle{scrheadings} % <--- Affects the page header  and page number in the footer.
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\leftmark}  % comment out to     
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
% Remove section number from heading

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\doublespacing 
\begin{document}
    
    %CHAPTER_1
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum
    
    \chapter{Project 1}
    
    %\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Package `classicthesis` loads package `typearea`. Therefore options `headinclude` and `footinclude=true` are allowed.  But `classicthesis` sets these options by default, if the class is not a KOMA-Script class. Note that `classicthesis` loads package `titlesec` that is incompatible with KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: @esdd  The OP is loading the report class + classicthesis + titleps (for page headers)

Comment: `classicthesis` loads among others package `scrlayer-scrpage` and package `titlesec`. Your option 1 loads `report` + `classicthesis` + `titleps`, ie. `report`+`scrlayer-scrpage`+`titleps`. Your option 2 loads  `scrreprt` + `classicthesis`, ie. `scrreprt` + `titlesec`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Not sure if this is the correct approach but by adding a `\newpage` before each `\chapter` solves the problem.